# Getting Qt Layout Direction to use right-to-left features (e.g. for Arabic) in cascading menus

Tags: c++, qt, arabic, qlayout

I'm writing a *QT5.5* application on *OS X 10.11*. I've implemented menu options to dynamically switch amongst languages, including setting the *Qt::LayoutDirection* for Right-to-Left languages. As mock-up for the right-to-left language support, I've created a test application and translation file in Arabic. Here's a screen-shot:

[image: menus_screenshot]

My complete ignorance of Arabic is not helping me here -- the translations shown come from Google Translate (I'll have the app professionally translated when it's finished). Nevertheless the behavior looks only partially correct.

These features match my expectations:

- "File"/"Edit"/"Options" menu items start from the right side of the screen
- The "Language" submenu of "Options" cascades to the left side of the main "Options" menu

The following features, however, do not match my expectations:

- The "First"/"Second"/"Third"/"Language" menu items of the "Options" menu are left-aligned instead of right aligned
- The checkmarks are on the left side of the entries instead of the right
- The submenu-cascade arrow for the "Language" submenu points right instead of left

My first question, therefore, is whether my expectations are wrong and the interface is in fact behaving correctly for Arabic, or alternatively what needs to be fixed?

***Update***: My Arabic-speaking colleagues confirm that the above screen-shot is wrong in the senses I mentioned, that instead it should look like this:

[image]

My second, and now main, question is how to fix whatever is wrong to make the Qt cascading menu behave properly for right-to-left languages?

I include below the full code for this standalone example as well as the Qt ".ts" file of translations I used.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QTranslator>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QMenu>

int
main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    QMainWindow* mw = new QMainWindow();

    QTranslator* translator = new QTranslator();

    translator->load( "translations.qm" );

    app.installTranslator( translator );

    app.setLayoutDirection( Qt::RightToLeft );

    QLabel* aLabel = new QLabel( mw );

    mw->menuBar()->setNativeMenuBar( false );

    QMenu* fileMenu = new QMenu( QMainWindow::tr( "File" ) );
    QMenu* editMenu = new QMenu( QMainWindow::tr( "Edit" ) );
    QMenu* optionsMenu = new QMenu( QMainWindow::tr( "Options" ) );

    mw->menuBar()->addMenu( fileMenu );
    mw->menuBar()->addMenu( editMenu );
    mw->menuBar()->addMenu( optionsMenu );

    QAction* firstAction = new QAction( QMainWindow::tr( "First" ), optionsMenu );
    QAction* secondAction = new QAction( QMainWindow::tr( "Second" ), optionsMenu );
    QAction* thirdAction = new QAction( QMainWindow::tr( "Third" ), optionsMenu );

    firstAction->setCheckable( true );
    firstAction->setChecked( true );

    optionsMenu->addAction( firstAction );
    optionsMenu->addAction( secondAction );
    optionsMenu->addAction( thirdAction );

    QMenu* languageMenu = new QMenu( QMainWindow::tr( "Language" ) );
    QAction* englishAction = new QAction( QMainWindow::tr( "English" ), languageMenu );
    QAction* arabicAction = new QAction( QMainWindow::tr( "Arabic" ), languageMenu );
    languageMenu->addAction( englishAction );
    languageMenu->addAction( arabicAction );
    optionsMenu->addMenu( languageMenu );

    mw->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

And the translations file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="en_US">
<context>
    <name>QMainWindow</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="qt_rtl.cc" line="21"/>
        <source>File</source>
        <translation>Ù~EÙ~DÙ~A</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="qt_rtl.cc" line="22"/>
        <source>Edit</source>
        <translation>ØªØ­Ø±Ù~JØ±</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="qt_rtl.cc" line="23"/>
        <source>Options</source>
        <translation>Ø®Ù~JØ§Ø±Ø§Øª</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="qt_rtl.cc" line="29"/>
        <source>First</source>
        <translation>Ø§Ù~DØ£Ù~HÙ~D</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="qt_rtl.cc" line="30"/>
        <source>Second</source>
        <translation>Ø«Ø§Ù~FÙ~JØ§</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="qt_rtl.cc" line="31"/>
        <source>Third</source>
        <translation>Ø«Ù~DØ«</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="qt_rtl.cc" line="40"/>
        <source>Language</source>
        <translation>Ù~DØºØ©</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="qt_rtl.cc" line="41"/>
        <source>English</source>
        <translation>English</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="qt_rtl.cc" line="42"/>
        <source>Arabic</source>
        <translation>Ø§Ù~DØ¹Ø±Ø¨Ù~JØ©</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

I would have hoped that the `app.setLayoutDirection( Qt::RightToLeft );` line would have "done the right thing" for all widgets and sub widgets but it does not appear so. Perhaps though it did? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you not using a native menu bar? The non-native menu bars are probably not really well debugged under OS X, since nobody should be using them... It's quite possible that you're the first person ever to see this misbehavior. On OS X, a menu bar inside of a window feels completely out of place and your users will be thoroughly baffled by it. You must also properly [set the roles](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11081831/1329652) for menu items, so that they'll behave properly on OS X.

Comment: Our applications run on multiple platforms and we want the user interface to be the same on all, which is what our particular users are used to. I respect your point that the non-native menu bars may not be the first choice for OS X, nevertheless they are present and available, so I'd hope they'd either be debugged to work properly, or alternatively disabled entirely.

Comment: As an OS X user, I'd not be happy about these menus, neither would I be if you used the scroll wheel for zoom when every shipping Apple system provides separate zoom and scroll inputs out of the box... Windows is going that way too. Applications with non-standard menus look very out of place - one gets so used to them that if I were to open your application, I might not even notice that there are menus inside the window. Never mind that you're wasting about 1/3 of an inch on top of the user's screen. It's dedicated to a menu, by not using it you put it to waste :(

Comment: "we want the user interface to be the same on all, which is what our particular users are used to" - in all likelihood, your app is the only app they run on OS X that wastes screen real estate with non-standard menus :( I completely agree that the non-native menu bar should behave correctly, but the reason it wasn't debugged was simply that nobody else needs it, because they shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact same code works fine with *Qt5.5* running on *CentOS 6.7 Linux*, i.e. with *X11* platform plugin instead of *Cocoa*:

[image: Cascading Arabic Qt Menus on Linux]

Note that the checkmarks are on the right, all text is right-aligned, and the submenu arrow points to the left, as they all should be.

Therefore the conclusion is that the above code is correct, and there appears to be a bug in *Cocoa* platform support for cascading menus in right-to-left languages under *Qt5.5* on *OS X*.